# Why might Java code run fine manually, but not from a Shell Script?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, permissions

Hi have a frustrating problem: On my Ubuntu 22.04 machine, I have some Java/Maven code which I can run manually from the command line:

```
me@UbuntuV2:~/home/me/path/to/Java/Code$
me@UbuntuV2:~/home/me/path/to/Java/Code$ mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------< MyCode.java >--------------------
...code runs fine...
```

This is great, but I need to run this same code from a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Running the script!"
cd /home/me/path/to/Java/Code
mvn test
echo "Script finished."
```

What's weird is that the script can launch the Java code, but the script-run code throws an exception:

```
me@UbuntuV2:~/home/me$
me@UbuntuV2:~/home/me$ ./runScript.sh
Running the script!
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------< MyCode.java >--------------------
2022-03-02 12:29:44,899 main ERROR Unable to access file:/home/me/path/to/Java/Code/src/test/resources/log4j2.xml java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/me/path/to/Java/Code/src/test/resources/log4j2.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:157)
    ...etc...
```

This is superweird, right? When run through the shell script, the Java code suddenly can't access a "log4j2.xml" file. ("No such file or directory") But the file is there, in place, and the code has no issues opening it when I run the code manually.

So what is different when I run the code manually? I've racked my brains trying to think of what could be different. I've done all of the following:

- Verified that user me manually runs the code from a bash shell, just like the script does.
- Run the script as user `me`, the same user who can run the code manually
- Verified that the script runs as me by adding a `whoami` command in the script to check
- Used a `pwd` command to verify that the script run the code from the correct directory
- Set the script's PATH variable to be the exact same Path as user `me` using the command `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:...` in the script
- Used the `visudo` command to ensure that user `me` has unlimited access to all files on the Ubuntu
- Made sure the user `me` owns the script and has execute rights
- Yelled and swore at the Ubuntu a lot

What else could the problem be?  I didn't write the Java code, so maybe the code itself refers to this log4j2.xml file by relative paths, not absolute paths...?  But if that's the case, why does the code work when manually run?

I know this is an open-ended question, but what else might be different between the script- and the human-initiated versions of running this code.  I've gotta be missing something...

FULL DISCLOSURE :: I've also posted this question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1395644/why-might-java-code-run-fine-manually-but-not-from-a-shell-script).

Comment: As a test, try commenting out the `cd ...` and running it as `/home/me/runScript.sh` from the project directory

Comment: Just to investigate, try 1) Reboot Ubuntu; 2) Do both tests; 3) Run second test like `source runScript.sh`

Comment: Could you have an alias for `mvn` set up in your interactive shell?  Compare the outputs of `type mvn` in your interactive shell and in the program (after the `PATH` is set if you are still setting it explicitly in the program.)

Comment: In an interactive shell where `mvn test` works, does `bash -c 'mvn test'` work?  That might help to flush out possible differences between interactive and non-interactive runs.

Comment: Try running both with [strace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace): `strace -f -o strace.mvn.out mvn test`, and `strace -f -o strace.bash.out ./runScript.sh`.  Assuming that the first succeeds and the other fails, look for differences in how the `mvn` process are starting and what they are doing after they start.  The output might contain more precise information about why accesses to some files are failing with the `mvn` run from the Bash program.

Comment: @LMC I tried that.  But invoking '/home/me/path/to/Java/Code/mvn test' from the command doesn't work either.  :(

Comment: What do you get from `echo "$SHELL"`. If it's not `/bin/bash` then that could be a lead

Comment: @Philippe - Interesting!  Once I reboot the Ubuntu, now the Java code throws the exception BOTH when I run it manually or through the code.  At least my problem is now consistent...  Thanks!

Comment: @LMC  Good catch!  No, a `echo "$SHELL"` confirms that I'm using `/bin/bash` on the command line, just like in the script.  So at least that's consistent.

Comment: @pjh  Interesting!  When I issue `type mvn` from the command line, I get `mvn is hashed (/usr/bin/mvn)`.  But when I do the same from within the script, I get `mvn is /usr/bin/mvn` - not the same!  I wonder what it could mean...?

Comment: @LMC No, sadly, its `/bin/bash` on both the command line and within the script.  UPDATE:  I rebooted the Ubuntu, and now I have the same problem with the Java code from both cmd line and the script.  So while the problem is bad, at least its consistent in both execution contexts.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Pete, the `type mvn` output actually shows that the same `mvn` is being run both interactively and non-interactively.  Interactive shells use a hashing mechanism to find commands faster after they've been used once, avoiding a potentially slow search of the `PATH`.  It's useful information, but your search for what is causing the problem will have to continue.  Sorry.

Comment: @pjh No, this is still useful information!  Thank you.  Its handy to be able to eliminate possibilities.  I really appreciate you writing!

Comment: Manually, you are in directory `~/home/me/path/to/Java/Code`, in your script you are in `/home/me/path/to/Java/Code`.  There could be an extra `~` expansion so the path is not exactly the same from the manual to the script version ?

Comment: @Nic3500 No, I'm pretty sure there's no extra character and the path for the manual execution matches the path in the script.  Thanks for the thought, tho!

Comment: Compare `me@UbuntuV2:~/home/me/path/to/Java/Code$` with `cd /home/me/path/to/Java/Code`.  You PS1 variable might be messed up then ?